# clock_nanosleep(): It ignores timespec structure

Tags: c, posix

I am trying to create this basic `clock_nanosleep` example but it will not pause my `for` loop which keeps on printing numbers. If I uncomment the `//t.tv_nsec = s/1000000000;` nothing will be printed, but `for` loop will be running.

```
// POSIX.1-2017 is what compiler is confined to.
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700

// C headers.
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
   
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Counter.
    uint8_t i;

    // Time.
    int s = 1;

    // Create a timespec structure and calculate it's members.
    struct timespec t;
    t.tv_sec = s;
    //t.tv_nsec = s/1000000000;

    // Set flags i.e. TIMER_ABSTIME to 0 to use relative instead of absolute time.
    int flags = 0;

    // Choose the clock i.e. CLOCK_MONOTONIC is a "clock_id" for the clock started at system start.
    int clock_id = CLOCK_MONOTONIC;

    for(i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        printf("%d", i);

        // Because last argument is NULL in case of error, remaining time is not stored in "t".
        clock_nanosleep(clock_id, flags, &t, NULL);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

I have absolutely no clue why this isn't working. POSIX states that:

> `int clock_nanosleep(clockid_t clock_id, int flags, const struct timespec *rqtp, struct timespec *rmtp);`
>
> If the flag `TIMER_ABSTIME` is not set in the flags
> argument, the `clock_nanosleep()` function shall cause the current
> thread to be suspended from execution until either the time interval
> specified by the `rqtp` argument has elapsed, or a signal is delivered
> to the calling thread and its action is to invoke a signal-catching
> function, or the process is terminated.

I made sure flag is zeroed out. And I set the `rqtp` i.e. `&t`.

> The clock used to measure the
> time shall be the clock specified by `clock_id`.

I did use the `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.

> If the `clock_nanosleep()` function returns because it has been
> interrupted by a signal, it shall return the corresponding error
> value. For the relative `clock_nanosleep()` function, if the `rmtp`
> argument is non `NULL`, the timespec structure referenced by it shall be
> updated to contain the amount of time remaining in the interval (the
> requested time minus the time actually slept). The `rqtp` and `rmtp`
> arguments can point to the same object. If the `rmtp` argument is `NULL`,
> the remaining time is not returned. The absolute `clock_nanosleep()`
> function has no effect on the structure referenced by `rmtp`.

I also set last argument to `NULL` in order not to store the remaining time if `clock_naanosleep()` is interrupted by any signal.

So why this doesn't work?

Comment: `s/1000000000` is integer division. if `s < 1000000000` result will be zero

Comment: What value do you think `t.tv_nsec = s/1000000000;` produces?

Comment: With `//t.tv_nsec = s/1000000000;`, `t.tv_nsec` is not assigned anywhere.  `clock_nanosleep()`   receiving garbage input.

Comment: Above garbage inputs are (from my experience) typically zeros.

Comment: @ImportAccelerate There's no guarantee of that, and OP's code / environment is a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables are not implicitly initialized.  So if you don't set `t.tv_nsec` it could contain any value.  If that value happens to be outside the range of 0 - 999999999 then `clock_nanosleep` will return immediately with an error code.

The reason you don't see any output when you do set `t.tv_nsec` is because of how you're printing:

```
 printf("%d", i);
```

You're not including a newline in the output.  The `stdout` stream is line buffered, so it won't automatically flush the output stream to the console.  Add `\n` to the end of the format string and you'll see the lines print.

Comment: Are `t.tv_nsec` and `t.tv_nsec` representing units or values for the time *(I mean in terms of physics)*?

Comment: `tv_sec` is seconds and `tv_nsec` is nano seconds.  So for example if you set `tv_sec` to 1 and `tv_nsec` to 500000000, then you sleep for 1.5 seconds.

Comment: So they add together?!?!?! Where is this written in POSIX?

Comment: Ok now I understand how this works. If anyone can point where in POSIX it is written that they add I will be glad. Because I can't find any information even by using CTRL + F... I think POSIX should make clear how this is used...

Comment: I don't think it's specifically written, but it wouldn't make sense for only one or the other to be set.  Otherwise you would only be given the option to specify nanoseconds.

Comment: Actually, the man page in Linux specifically says the range for tv_nsec is 0 .. 999999999.

Comment: IMHO I think *standard* should absolutely and explicitly write down what these values mean. C programming for Linux / POSIX would not even be hard if standard was  more explicit. But it is not and it let's us wonder arround and waste our time...

Comment: I know. I read all about the types of the members in `types.h` but description, meaning and application of these members is not written at all.

Answer (score 2):

In case like this you should *always* check what the actual return value is, which in this case will be `EINVAL` as the `t.tv.nsec` was not initialized.

Use:

```
struct timespec t = {
    .tv_sec = s,
};
```

To properly initialize *all* of the fields, even the ones you do not intend to use.